# Update forms in FutureBuilder

Tags: database, flutter, forms, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to be able to update my forms in a futureBuilder. I need the futureBuilder to retrieve all the datas from the player in my DataBase. I am setting my initial values of my form right after I got the datas. When I'm trying to update de date using the Icon and DatePicker, the text doesn't change. The date is store in my "age" variable.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cleanmaybe/Controllers/players_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'login_form_view.dart';

class PlayerStatView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerStatView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayerStatView> createState() => _PlayerStatViewState();
}

class _PlayerStatViewState extends State<PlayerStatView> {
  late Future<dynamic> dataFuture;
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  File? imageFile;
  File? theNewPic;
  String filepath = "";
  File? image;
  File? imageFile2;
  late String pName;
  late String lName;
  late String phonePlayer;
  late String age;

  Future<void> _openImagePicker(ImageSource source) async {
    final XFile? pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: source);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        theNewPic = File(pickedImage.path);
        filepath = theNewPic!.path;
      });
      print(pickedImage);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataFuture = getAllPlayerData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double imageSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4;
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', ''),
        Locale('fr', ''), // arabic, no country code
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Profil du joueur"),
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text("Attention !"),
                      content: const Text(
                          "Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce profil?"),
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              deletePlayer(context);
                              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                            },
                            child: const Text("Oui")),
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                            },
                            child: const Text("non"))
                      ],
                    );
                    showDialog(
                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
                          return alert;
                        });
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const LoginFormView()),
                        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app))
            ]),
        body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
            future: dataFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var data = snapshot.data;
              if (data == null) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                pName = data[0]['firstName'];
                lName = data[0]['lastName'];
                imageFile = File(data[0]['photoName']);
                phonePlayer = data[0]['phone'];
                age = data[0]['age'];
               // age = data[0]['age'];
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          elevation: 10,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 200,
                                    child: getImageChange(context))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 128,
                        ),
/*                        SizedBox(
                          width: 125,
                        ),*/
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: (() =>
                              _openImagePicker(ImageSource.camera)),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_rounded),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 40,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: (() =>
                              _openImagePicker(ImageSource.gallery)),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.photo_album_outlined),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      thickness: 0,
                    ),
                    myTitle("Données du joueur"),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                            child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            initialValue: pName,
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                              setState(() {
                                pName = value;
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: "Prénom",
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person)),
                          ),
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                            child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            initialValue: lName,
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                              setState(() {
                                lName = value;
                              });
                            },
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: "Nom de famille",
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person)),
                          ),
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                initialValue: phonePlayer,
                                onChanged: (String value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    phonePlayer = value;
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    labelText: "Numéro de téléphone",
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone)),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          //Icon(Icons.cake),
                          Text("Date de naissance: "),

                          Builder(builder: (context) {
                            return IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                              onPressed: () {
                                showDatePicker(
                                  locale: const Locale("fr", "FR"),
                                  context: context,
                                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  firstDate: DateTime(1980),
                                  lastDate: DateTime(2050),
                                ).then((value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    String formattedDate =
                                    DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(value!);
                                    age = formattedDate;
                                    print(age);
                                  });
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          }),
                          Flexible(
                            child: TextFormField(initialValue: age, onChanged: (String value){
                              setState(() {
                                age = value;
                              });
                            },),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                ));
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final chosenFile = await picker.pickImage(source: source);
    if (chosenFile == null) {
      print("j'ai rien");
    } else {
      var changing = File(chosenFile.path);
      return changing;
    }
  }

  Widget getImageChange(context) {
    double imageSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4;
    if (theNewPic == null) {
      if (imageFile?.path == '') {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 10,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                  Text(
                    "Ajoutez une photo",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return Image.file(
          imageFile!,
          height: imageSize,
          width: imageSize,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        );
      }
    } else {
      return Image.file(
        theNewPic!,
        height: imageSize,
        width: imageSize,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      );
    }
  }
}

Text myTitle(String text) {
  return Text(text,
      style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18));
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve it ? if not I can provide a working solution